# View time spent in a platform

Tags: xapi, learning-locker

My goal is to track how much time is spent on a platform and then show it as a visual in Learning Locker. However, when I POST the statements and try to create a visual of it, nothing shows. How should I be doing this?

I have posted the xAPI statements as follows:

```json
[
    {
        "actor": {
            "objectType": "Agent",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "mbox": "mailto:john.doe@example.com"
        },
        "verb": {
            "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/experienced",
            "display": {
                "en-US": "experienced"
            }
        },
        "object": {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://example.com/activities/metaverse-platform",
            "definition": {
                "name": {
                    "en-US": "Metaverse Platform"
                },
                "description": {
                    "en-US": "Time spent in the Metaverse platform"
                }
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "duration": "PT2H"
        },
        "timestamp": "2024-01-15T00:00:00Z"
    },
    {
        "actor": {
            "objectType": "Agent",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "mbox": "mailto:john.doe@example.com"
        },
        "verb": {
            "id": "http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/experienced",
            "display": {
                "en-US": "experienced"
            }
        },
        "object": {
            "objectType": "Activity",
            "id": "http://example.com/activities/metaverse-platform",
            "definition": {
                "name": {
                    "en-US": "Metaverse Platform"
                },
                "description": {
                    "en-US": "Time spent in the Metaverse platform"
                }
            }
        },
        "result": {
            "duration": "PT4H"
        },
        "timestamp": "2024-01-16T00:00:00Z"
    }
]
```

And it shows in the Source tab on LL. But when I try to make a bar chart, I can't figure out how to display it. I assume I need to do *Sum of*, and then Raw Results. But nothing shows when I select this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using Learning Locker to track xAPI statements and visualize the time spent on a platform. However, there might be an issue with how the data is being presented or interpreted in the visualization tool. Let's troubleshoot and clarify a few things:

1. **Data Format:** The xAPI statements you provided seem to be correctly formatted, with actor, verb, object, result, and timestamp fields.
2. **Visualization Setup:** In Learning Locker, when creating a visualization like a bar chart, you typically need to specify which data you want to visualize and how you want it aggregated.
3. **Aggregation:** Since you want to visualize the time spent on the platform, you indeed need to aggregate the durations. You can use the "Sum of" option to aggregate the durations.
4. **Data Selection:** When selecting the data for visualization, make sure you're choosing the correct fields. In this case, you want to visualize the duration of time spent on the Metaverse platform.
5. **Date Range:** Ensure that the date range you've selected for the visualization includes the timestamps of the xAPI statements you posted.
6. **Visualization Type:** A bar chart should be suitable for visualizing aggregated durations.

Here's what you can try:

1. In Learning Locker, go to the visualization tool or the area where you create visualizations.
2. Choose to create a new visualization, and select the bar chart type.
3. When prompted to select data, choose the "Sum of" option and select the duration field.
4. Make sure you've selected the correct date range that includes the timestamps of your xAPI statements.
5. Confirm that you're visualizing the data for the Metaverse platform activity.
6. Once you've set up the visualization parameters correctly, try generating the chart again.

> If you're still encountering issues, there might be a problem with how
> Learning Locker interprets or handles the xAPI statements. In that
> case, you may need to consult Learning Locker's documentation or
> support resources for further assistance. Additionally,
> double-checking your xAPI statements for any errors or inconsistencies
> could also be helpful.